# mysql query problem with multiple table relations

Tags: mysql

I have problems to query my data. Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `myString` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `myStringId1` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `myStringId2` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index1` (`myStringId1`),
  KEY `index2` (`myStringId2`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_B2` FOREIGN KEY (`myStringId2`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_B1` FOREIGN KEY (`myStringId1`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

where **myStringId1** and **myStringId2** have foreign key constraints to TABLE A (**id**)

Ok let me clarify what I want to achieve by  query:
Lets assume some values for the given tables:

```
TABLE A:
ROW1: 22, "foo"
ROW2: 33, "bar"

TABLE B: 
ROW1: 1, 22, 33, "true"
ROW2: 2, 22, 22, "false"
```

Now what I need is a query where I give String "foo" and get the following result from joining the two tables:

```
RESULT:
ROW1: "foo","bar", "true"
ROW2: "foo", "foo", "false"
```

given String "bar" I expect this:

RESULT:
   ROW1: "foo","bar","true"

any ideas ?

Comment: can you please explain your request more? It is not clear what results do you desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comment I think this is closer to what you need:

```
SELECT a1.myString as myString1, a2.myString as myString2, b.value
FROM `B` b
    JOIN `A` a1 on a1.id = b.myStringId1
    JOIN `A` a2 on a2.id = b.myStringId2
WHERE a1.myString = 'SOME STRING' OR a2.myString = 'SOME STRING'
```

The two joins will ensure the both `b.myStringId1` and `b.myStringId2` are existing keys for `TABLE A`, and the `WHERE` ensures that one of those 2 strings is the one you need.

Comment: well joining one table multiple times is interesting. I will experiment with this. Anyway the problem is I want to select one or more lines from Table B which contains only IDs (myStringId1,myStringId2) that are foreign keys to TABLE A and where the actual string representation in TABLE A should match one or the other given string. Does this make things clearer ?